# Dynamically set multiple object properties using variable

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I wanna set multiple object property with the same value.

```
const SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG = 'SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG';
const SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG = 'SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG';

const handler = (state, payload) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        data: payload
    };
  };

const object = {
  [SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG]: handler,
  [SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG]: handler,
};
```

As above example, I have to manually assign handler for 2 property `SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG` & `SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG`

Is there anyway to set it quickly **on the fly** by js api but no need to introduce a new function to handle that like

```
const object = {
      [SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG, SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG]: handler,
    };
```

Comment: Why don’t you use a method for it then compare the parameter to return the function that you requiere.

Comment: @BobWhite, sorry I didnt get what you mean :-?

Comment: someone have already answered you question. it was what i meant.

Comment: There is no shortcut for assigning value to multiple keys at once yet, other than  the old `obj.a = obj.b = value`. What you have is the most readable and concise.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.fromEntries()` with `.map()` if you're okay with having the same reference to `handler` for each value... (the snippet console output shows how the handler method is the same reference for each value, that's why it looks a little strange):

```js
const SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG = 'SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG';
const SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG = 'SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG';

const handler = (state, payload) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    data: payload
  };
};

const keys = [SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG, SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG];
const object = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, handler]));

console.log(object);
```

Please note that `.fromEntries()` is currently in [*draft mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Specifications), however, I think a generic `if` statement accompanied with a Set (using `.has()`) would be better for this case than using an object:

```js
const SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG = 'SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG';
const SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG = 'SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG';

const handler = (state, payload) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    data: payload
  };
};

const get_handler = key => {
  const keys = new Set([SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG, SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG]);
  if(keys.has(key))
    return handler;
}

console.log(get_handler(SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG)); // hanlder
console.log(get_handler("foo")); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic function and pass an array of key and loop through `keyArr` and place value for each key

```js
const SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG = 'SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG';
const SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG = 'SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG';

let value = "some value"
const object = { someKey: 'value'};

let dynamicSetValues = (keyArr, value) => {
  keyArr.forEach(key => {
    object[key] = value
  })
}

dynamicSetValues(['SHOW_PAYMENT_DIALOG','SHOW_BUSINESS_DIALOG'], value)

console.log(object)
```

***Note:-*** this mutates original object, if you want immutability you can make a copy of object and place value on desired keys and return a new object every time from function

Comment: cool, I'm also thinking about that. I'm just curious about the faster way which is supported by `es6`

Comment: Only direct way is to define manually, else you need to loop if you dont want to repeat yourself writing the same thing again and again